# ¿Cómo verificar que un archivo exista en Python?

Tags: python, archivo

Usando Python, ¿cómo verifico si un archivo existe?, sin usar la sentencia `try`.

**Pregunta original**:

- [Check whether a file exists using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python) de [spence91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15616/spence91)

Comment: No entiendo el -1 en esta pregunta, ¿es simplemente porque se trajo de SO? :/

Comment: @OSjerick parece que si

Comment: +1 porque es wiki de comunidad!.

Comment: @Elenasys gracias, me alegro que compartas la misma idea

Comment: -1 por falta de investigación.  ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: @Flimzy nuevamente, no es mi pregunta

Comment: Yo sé que no es tu pregunta... pero eso no cambia los estándares de calidad. Si quieres preguntar cosas de otras personas, no es pretexto de hacer preguntas de baja calidad.

Comment: @Flimzy bueno la verdad que este tema ya esta empezando a aburrir. Estoy respetando la pregunta original, si modifico algo despues otros se quejan de que estoy haciendo plagio. Hasta que se decidan, seguiré haciendo lo mismo

Comment: Ahora, en Python 3.4 o superior, la mejor forma es [pathlib.Path.exists()](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists), siendo pathlib de la librería estandar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Puedes usar `os.path.isfile`:

> Retorna `True` si la ruta es un archivo regular existente. Sigue los links simbólicos
>   , de tal manera que [`islink()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink) y [`isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) pueden ser verdaderos para la misma ruta.

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

Si necesitas estar seguro de que es un archivo.

**Respuesta original:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/82852/688393 de [rslite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15682/rslite)

---

Puedes utilizar el método indicado por @campussano haciendo uso de `os.path.exists()`:

```
import os.path as path

if path.exists(file):
   # código
```

La diferencia con `isfile()` es que `os.path.exists()` retornará `True` para archivos y carpetas

---

Puedes usar el método presentado por @toledano usando el módulo [unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath) el cual no viene incluído en Python y es necesario instalar previamente:

```
$ pip install unipath
```

Ejemplo:

```
from unipath import Path
f = Path('ejemplo.txt')
f.exists()
```

En general el uso de `unipath.Path` se me hace más simple que `os.path`, sobre todo a la hora de crear rutas.

```
# con os.path
os.path.join(A, B)

# con unipath.Path
Path(A, B)
```

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada

Comment: @LuisMasuelli claro, es un wiki, estoy centralizando las respuestas de los demás

Comment: Se están poniendo a migrar manualmente las preguntas y respuestas del sitio en ingles? Me parece teoricamente bueno pero practicamente muy dificil y largo xD.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli pues algunos se han vuelto medio frenéticos con el tema, no les gusta y le dan -1, yo creo que es necesario, la idea es generar una base de conocimiento en este sitio. Hay gente que no habla o escribe en inglés pero parecen no entenderlo

Comment: Te acabo de upvotear por el esfuerzo, y porque la pregunta es bastante util. Pero solo puedo dar un upvote.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli gracias por la consideración, es una de varias que pienso traducir y convertir en wikis comunitarios para futuras referencias

Comment: Voy a empezar tmb con mis preguntas y respuestas

Comment: @LuisMasuelli dale compañero, sigamos con el esfuerzo. Recuerda darle referencia a las preguntas/respuestas y autores originales

Answer (score 8):

Creo que también puedes utilizar:

```
import os.path as path
if (path.exists(file)):
   #todo::
```

Comment: La diferencia es que `exists()` retorna `True` también para las carpetas. Pero es válido. Otro punto, en Python no es necesario el uso de paréntesis en las sentencias `if`

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias.

Answer (score 6):

El módulo [`Unipath`](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath) también tiene un método `.exists()`.

```
from unipath import Path
f = Path('ejemplo.txt')
f.exists()
```

En general el uso de `unipath.Path` se me hace más simple que `os.path`, sobre todo a la hora de crear rutas.

```
# con os.path
os.path.join(A, B)

# con unipath.Path
Path(A, B)
```

Comment: Gracias! No conocía esa librería

Answer (score 1):

Complementando las respuestas, esta es la forma en que yo verifico exista un archivo en `Python`:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(archivo):
```

[`isFile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) retorna `true` con archivos o directorios.

> ```
> os.path.isfile(path)
> ```
>
> Regresa `true` si la ruta es un archivo existente. Esto sigue
>   los enlaces simbólicos, por lo tanto `IsLink ()` y `isfile ()` puede
>   ser verdadero para la misma ruta.

Comment: Elena, `isfile()` no funciona para directorios, solo para archivos

Comment: me refiero a que retorna true para directorios.

Comment: En Linux `os.path.isfile('/')` retorna `False`